# Static executable weird behaviour when running it in older FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, compiling

I did compile a cmake project statically in FreeBSD 12, when I try `ldd executable` it returns `not a dynamic executable`. I tried the executable in same computer and It works fine. Then I did port it to my vps that have a FreeBSD 12 and it's working like expected. But when I port it to FreeBSD 8. Some commands are working, like `executable --help` which print the help. But when I try some functions which Involve's networking (network is configured and I tried various programs like curl and php), the process exits silently, no segmentation fault or whatsoever, and after running the executable some other file name `executable.core` is added to the same directory

This is my first time compiling a FreeBSD build so I don't knew what I'm missing

Comment: Looks like now is the time to learn how to use a debugger... Even if statically compiled, a binary will make assumptions about the operating system that might not be valid in a significantly older version. When the program leaves a core file, some exception such as a segmentation fault has certainly happened.

Comment: Did you port it to FreeBSD 8 or copy the binary?

Comment: @Richard Smith, no I did copy it. Does it matter when we have a static executable?

Comment: FreeBSD contains a number of kernel options (`COMPAT_xxx`) and libraries (`misc/compat...`) to allow older binaries to run on newer machines, which implies to me that newer binaries are not expected to run on older machines due to changes in the ABI over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FreeBSD 12 had serious ABI change called "ino64". IIRC, libc can handle that when linked dynamically, so I'd try that first. If that doesn't work, your only option is to compile on FreeBSD 8.

Generally, you shouldn't expect binary compiled on X major release to work on X-1 release. But it works other way around by installing `misc/compatXX` packages.